# Displaying Links to Products or Categories from the Controller Servlet into jsp pages

Tags: java, jsp, jstl, el

I'm trying to link products to their own jsp page after a user chose a given product. I'm doing something wrong because the data doesn't display once on the product.jsp.

I try to retrieve the data with the variable `selectedProduct` but it seems the application doesn't recognize it or doesn't know where to retrieve the data for the variable`selectedProduct`.

I don't know why since, in my opinion, `selectedProduct` would be the same as `selectedCategory`... Apparently it is not... Why?  Am I missing something?

I've been going through solutions for the past week. Any help is more than welcomed!

Controller Servlet:

```
package controller;


import cart.ShoppingCart;
import wishlist.Wishlist;
import entity.Category;
import entity.Product;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.util.Collection;
import javax.ejb.EJB;
import javax.servlet.ServletConfig;
import javax.servlet.ServletException;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletRequest;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletResponse;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpSession;
import session.CategoryFacade;
import session.ProductFacade;

public class ControllerServlet extends HttpServlet {


    @EJB
    private CategoryFacade categoryFacade;
    @EJB
    private ProductFacade productFacade;

 @Override
    protected void doGet(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response)
    throws ServletException, IOException {

        String userPath = request.getServletPath();
        HttpSession session = request.getSession();
        Category selectedCategory;
        Product selectedProduct;
        Collection<Product> categoryProducts;



      // if category page is requested
            if (userPath.equals("/category")) {

                // get categoryId from request
                String categoryId = request.getQueryString();

                if (categoryId != null) {

                    // get selected category
                    selectedCategory = categoryFacade.find(Short.parseShort(categoryId));

                    // place selected category in session scope
                    session.setAttribute("selectedCategory", selectedCategory);

                    // get all products for selected category
                    categoryProducts = selectedCategory.getProductCollection();

                    // place category products in session scope
                    session.setAttribute("categoryProducts", categoryProducts);
                }


            // if product page is requested
            if (userPath.equals("/product")) {

                // get productId from request
                String productId = request.getQueryString();

                 if (productId != null) {

                // get selected product
                selectedProduct = productFacade.find(Short.parseShort(productId));

// place selected product in session scope
                session.setAttribute("selectedProduct", selectedProduct);
            }}
```

## EDIT BASED ON REQUEST

**Product.java:**

```
package entity;

import java.io.Serializable;
import java.math.BigDecimal;
import java.util.Collection;
import java.util.Date;
import javax.persistence.Basic;
import javax.persistence.CascadeType;
import javax.persistence.Column;
import javax.persistence.Entity;
import javax.persistence.GeneratedValue;
import javax.persistence.GenerationType;
import javax.persistence.Id;
import javax.persistence.JoinColumn;
import javax.persistence.Lob;
import javax.persistence.ManyToMany;
import javax.persistence.NamedQueries;
import javax.persistence.NamedQuery;
import javax.persistence.OneToMany;
import javax.persistence.Table;
import javax.persistence.Temporal;
import javax.persistence.TemporalType;
import javax.validation.constraints.NotNull;
import javax.validation.constraints.Size;
import javax.xml.bind.annotation.XmlRootElement;
import javax.xml.bind.annotation.XmlTransient;

/**
 *
 * @author PC
 */
@Entity
@Table(name = "product")
@XmlRootElement
@NamedQueries({
    @NamedQuery(name = "Product.findAll", query = "SELECT p FROM Product p"),
    @NamedQuery(name = "Product.findById", query = "SELECT p FROM Product p WHERE p.id = :id"),
    @NamedQuery(name = "Product.findByName", query = "SELECT p FROM Product p WHERE p.name = :name"),
    @NamedQuery(name = "Product.findByPrice", query = "SELECT p FROM Product p WHERE p.price = :price"),
    @NamedQuery(name = "Product.findByDescription", query = "SELECT p FROM Product p WHERE p.description = :description"),
    @NamedQuery(name = "Product.findByLastUpdate", query = "SELECT p FROM Product p WHERE p.lastUpdate = :lastUpdate")})
public class Product implements Serializable {
    @Basic(optional = false)
    @NotNull
    @Size(min = 1, max = 45)
    @Column(name = "price")
    private BigDecimal price;
    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    @Basic(optional = false)
    @Column(name = "id")
    private Integer id;
    @Basic(optional = false)
    @NotNull
    @Lob
    @Size(min = 1, max = 16777215)
    @Column(name = "name")
    private String name;
    @Lob
    @Size(max = 2147483647)
    @Column(name = "description")
    private String description;
    @Basic(optional = false)
    @NotNull
    @Column(name = "last_update")
    @Temporal(TemporalType.TIMESTAMP)
    private Date lastUpdate;
    @JoinColumn(name = "category_id", referencedColumnName = "id")
    @ManyToMany(mappedBy = "productCollection")
    private Collection<Category> categoryCollection;
    @OneToMany(cascade = CascadeType.ALL, mappedBy = "product")
    private Collection<OrderedProduct> orderedProductCollection;


    /**
     *
     */
    public Product() {
    }

    /**
     *
     * @param id
     */
    public Product(Integer id) {
        this.id = id;
    }

    /**
     *
     * @param id
     * @param name
     * @param price
     * @param lastUpdate
     */
    public Product(Integer id, String name, BigDecimal price, Date lastUpdate) {
        this.id = id;
        this.name = name;
        this.price = price;
        this.lastUpdate = lastUpdate;
    }

    /**
     *
     * @return
     */
    public Integer getId() {
        return id;
    }

    /**
     *
     * @param id
     */
    public void setId(Integer id) {
        this.id = id;
    }

    /**
     *
     * @return
     */
    public String getName() {
        return name;
    }


    /**
     *
     * @param name
     */
    public void setName(String name) {
        this.name = name;
    }


    /**
     *
     * @return
     */
    public String getDescription() {
        return description;
    }

    /**
     *
     * @param description
     */
    public void setDescription(String description) {
        this.description = description;
    }

    /**
     *
     * @return
     */
    public Date getLastUpdate() {
        return lastUpdate;
    }

    /**
     *
     * @param lastUpdate
     */
    public void setLastUpdate(Date lastUpdate) {
        this.lastUpdate = lastUpdate;
    }

    /**
     *
     * @return
     */
    @XmlTransient
    public Collection<Category> getCategoryCollection() {
        return categoryCollection;
    }

    /**
     *
     * @param categoryCollection
     */
    public void setCategoryCollection(Collection<Category> categoryCollection) {
        this.categoryCollection = categoryCollection;
    }

    /**
     *
     * @return
     */
    @XmlTransient
    public Collection<OrderedProduct> getOrderedProductCollection() {
        return orderedProductCollection;
    }

    /**
     *
     * @param orderedProductCollection
     */
    public void setOrderedProductCollection(Collection<OrderedProduct> orderedProductCollection) {
        this.orderedProductCollection = orderedProductCollection;
    }

    @Override
    public int hashCode() {
        int hash = 0;
        hash += (id != null ? id.hashCode() : 0);
        return hash;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean equals(Object object) {
        // TODO: Warning - this method won't work in the case the id fields are not set
        if (!(object instanceof Product)) {
            return false;
        }
        Product other = (Product) object;
        return !((this.id == null && other.id != null) || (this.id != null && !this.id.equals(other.id)));
    }

    @Override
    public String toString() {
        return "entity.Product[ id=" + id + " ]";
    }

    public BigDecimal getPrice() {
        return price;
    }

    public void setPrice(BigDecimal price) {
        this.price = price;
    }
}
```

Product.jsp

```
<table style="text-align: left; width: 100%; height: 172px;" border="0" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0">

    <tbody>
        <tr>
            <td colspan="1" rowspan="6" style="vertical-align: top;">product_gallery<br></td>
            <td colspan="1" rowspan="6" style="vertical-align: top;"><img class="img" src="${initParam.productBigImagePath}${product.name}.jpg"><br></td>
            <td style="vertical-align: top;">${selectedProduct.name}<br></td>
            <td style="vertical-align: top;"><br></td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td style="vertical-align: top;">$ ${selectedProduct.price}</td>
            <td style="vertical-align: top;"><br></td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td style="vertical-align: top;"><br></td>
            <td style="vertical-align: top;"><br></td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td style="vertical-align: top;"><br></td>
            <td style="vertical-align: top;"><br></td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td colspan="2" rowspan="1" style="vertical-align: top;">${selectedProduct.description}</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td style="vertical-align: top;">
                <form action="addToWishlist" method="post"><br><br> 
                    <input name="productId" value="${product.id}" type="hidden"> 
                    <input class="submit" onclick="addedWishlist()" value="<fmt:message key='AddToWishlist'/>" type="submit"> 
                </form><br>
            </td>
            <td style="vertical-align: top;">
                <form action="addToCart" method="post"><br><br> 
                    <input name="productId" value="${product.id}" type="hidden">
                    <input class="submit" onclick="addedCart()" value="<fmt:message key='AddToCart'/>" type="submit"> 
                </form>
            </td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td style="vertical-align: top;"><br></td>
            <td style="vertical-align: top;"><br></td>
            <td colspan="2" rowspan="1" style="vertical-align: top;">
                <ul>
                    <li style="background-color: rgb(198, 255, 201); width:100%; text-align:center; border-radius:2em;">
                        <a href="${value}"><fmt:message key='ContinueShopping'/></a>
                    </li>
                </ul>
                <br>
            </td>
        </tr>
    </tbody>
</table>
```

Category.jsp

```
<table style="text-align: left; width: 100%;" border="0" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="40px">

  <c:forEach var="product" items="${categoryProducts}" varStatus="iter">

    <td>
      <tbody>
        <tr>
          <td style="vertical-align: middle; text-align: center;" class="cell">
            <a href="product?${product.id}">



              <img class="img" alt="" src="${initParam.productImagePath}${product.name}.jpg" />

              <div class="caption">
                <br>view details</div>

            </a>
            <br>


          </td>
          <td style="vertical-align: middle; width: 140px; text-align: center; ">${product.name}
            <br>
          </td>
          <td style="vertical-align: middle; width: 120px; text-align: center; line-height:100%;">$${product.price}
            <br>
          </td>
          <td style="vertical-align: middle; width: 136px; text-align: center; line-height:20%;">

            <form id="wishlistForm" action="addToWishlist" method="post">
              <br>
              <br>
              <input name="productId" value="${product.id}" type="hidden">

              <input class="submit" onclick="addedWishlist()" value="<fmt:message key='AddToWishlist'/>" type="submit">
            </form>
            <br>
          </td>
          <td style="vertical-align: middle; width: 136px; text-align: center; line-height:20%;">


            <form id="cartForm" action="addToCart" method="post">
              <br>
              <br>

              <input name="productId" value="${product.id}" type="hidden">
              <input class="submit" onclick="addedCart()" value="<fmt:message key='AddToCart'/>" type="submit">


            </form>
            <br>
          </td>
        </tr>
      </tbody>
  </c:forEach>
</table>
```

Comment: Questions seeking debugging help ("why isn't this code working?") must include ... **the shortest** code necessary to reproduce it in the question itself

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're setting as session attribute a `selectProduct` which is an individual product:

```
Product selectedProduct;
...
session.setAttribute("selectedProduct", selectedProduct);
```

`<c:forEach>` in JSTL tags is for `Collections, Lists or Arrays` not for individual objects.

Due this it's normal that your first scenario with: `<c:forEach var="product" items="${selectedProduct}" varStatus="iter"></c:forEach>` it's blank, because you cannot iterate over a simple bean.

In your second scenario you're iterating over `${categoryProducts}`. I suppose that you are setting this object as session attribute (it's not show in your snippet but surely is on it), at least this object is a collection, so in your server I suppose you've:

```
Collection<Product> categoryProducts;
...
session.setAttribute("categoryProducts", categoryProducts);
```

In this case if you are using `<c:forEach var="product" items="${categoryProducts}" varStatus="iter"></c:forEach>` you're iterating over all products in this category this is why all products appears in your page.

In your third case like the second one you are using `<c:forEach var="product" items="${categoryProducts}" varStatus="iter"></c:forEach>`, so you're assigning each step of the loop an element from `categoryProducts` collection to a `product` object, however inside this loop you're using `${selectedProduct}` instead of `${product}` so for each iteration you're using the same object instead of the object give it from the collection.

I think if you want to show only one `product` in your `product.jsp`, and this `product` is stored on `selectedProduct` session attributte, then to solve your problem don't use `<c:forEach>`, remove it from your `product.jsp` (since you only want to show one product), and in the jsp code use `${selectedProduct.yourProperty}` instead of `${product.yourProperty}`.

**EDIT BASED ON COMMENT**

Try with the follow `product.jsp`, if it continues to show a blank page, check that you're really setting a session attribute named `selectedProduct` with your product, and it has a value for it's members (`selectProduct.getName()`, `selectProduct.getDescription()`, `selectProduct.getPrice()` are not blank). Check the code inside your `if`, maybe it's never executed or in case it's executed your `selectProduct` has some empty fields

```
       if (productId != null) {

            // get selected product
            selectedProduct = productFacade.find(Short.parseShort(productId));

            // place selected product in session scope
            session.setAttribute("selectedProduct", selectedProduct);
        }
```

**Product.jsp:**

```
<table style="text-align: left; width: 100%; height: 172px;" border="0" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0">
    <tbody>
        <tr>
            <td colspan="1" rowspan="6" style="vertical-align: top;">product_gallery<br></td>
            <td colspan="1" rowspan="6" style="vertical-align: top;"><img class="img" src="${initParam.productBigImagePath}${selectedProduct.name}.jpg"><br></td>
            <td style="vertical-align: top;">${selectedProduct.name}<br></td>
            <td style="vertical-align: top;"><br></td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td style="vertical-align: top;">$ ${selectedProduct.price}</td>
            <td style="vertical-align: top;"><br></td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td style="vertical-align: top;"><br></td>
            <td style="vertical-align: top;"><br></td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td style="vertical-align: top;"><br></td>
            <td style="vertical-align: top;"><br></td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td colspan="2" rowspan="1" style="vertical-align: top;">${selectedProduct.description}</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td style="vertical-align: top;">
                <form action="addToWishlist" method="post"><br><br> 
                    <input name="productId" value="${selectedProduct.id}" type="hidden"> 
                    <input class="submit" value="<fmt:message key='AddToWishlist'/>" type="submit"> 
                </form><br>
            </td>
            <td style="vertical-align: top;">
                <form action="addToCart" method="post"><br><br> 
                    <input name="productId" value="${selectedProduct.id}" type="hidden">
                    <input class="submit" value="<fmt:message key='AddToCart'/>"type="submit"> 
                </form>
            </td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td style="vertical-align: top;"><br></td>
            <td style="vertical-align: top;"><br></td>
            <td colspan="2" rowspan="1" style="vertical-align: top;">
                <ul>
                    <li style="background-color: rgb(198, 255, 201); width:100%; text-align:center; border-radius:2em;">
                        <a href="${value}"><fmt:message key='ContinueShopping'/></a>
                    </li>
                </ul>
                <br>
            </td>
        </tr>
    </tbody>
</table>
```

Hope this helps,

Comment: Thanks for your help, I didn't even think about removing the each statement... Now when I click on a product, the product.jsp displays with only one product but no data appears on the page just like in the 3rd scenario... I ran 2 tests: First one I used `${selectedProduct.yourProperty}` and second one I used `${product.yourProperty}`... Both give the same results: the product.jsp displays without data.

Comment: I think in order to retrieve the data for the product, I need to add a line of code in the `Servlet` like: `Product = selectedProduct.getProductCollection();
    }`... Of course I know calling `collection` would get all the items, which isn't what we want... But I have no clue how to just call one single product...

Comment: @user23524697 I update my answer, take a look `:)`. If after the checks I suggest all seems correct and page persist to not display, can you share your `Product` class? hope this helps `:)`

Comment: Thanks. I made the changes and replaced it with your codes. Still returns blank so as you requested, I shared my `product` class. Hope it helps! I will be running some more tests on my side. Maybe i`ve been looking at my code for too long lol... it might be something stupid who knows lol.

Comment: @user23524697 product class seems ok to get the field values back from jsp... did you check that really the `selectProduct` you put in the session has values for this fields?

Comment: excuse my beginner experience, how would I do that, where do I need to look?

Comment: @user23524697 it seems that `selectedProduct` doesn't have the values you expect, so I recommend that you debug your code in order to see  what is really happening. As you said in your comment if you don't know how to debug a remote java application you can take a look here: `http://java.dzone.com/articles/how-debug-remote-java-applicat` . Hope this helps

Comment: Thanks for your help. I think I understand the problem with your input... The application doesn't understand where the product comes from after clicking on it, therefore it doesn't know where to retrieve the data for the `selectedProduct`, as if it doesn't recognize the variable `selectedProduct` ? Are you saying I should try retrieving the data from a `selectedCategory` so it knows a given product comes from its given `selectedCategory`?

Comment: I pasted the code I use to retrieve data for categories. See the controller servlet `:)`

Comment: @user23524697 yes, at first (now probably is different since you change your code) the problem was that you were using for example `${selectedProduct.id}` in the jsp however you're not setting `selectProduct` in the server (in your case in the session). And you were also using `<c:forEach>` for a element (not collection, array...). I don't know if this responds your question.

Comment: @user23524697 sorry english is not my language... and probably I try to explain the problem badly.

Comment: No I didn't change the code. I just added the code I use to retrieve data from the category.class so you can see.

Comment: I understand what you're trying to explain. I should look in the session pack?

Comment: @user23524697 you change your code, you remove `session.setAttribute("selectedProduct", selectedProduct);` in the third edit revision. If there is not `selectProduct` in session you can not use it in jsp.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/73624/discussion-between-albciff-and-user23524697).

Comment: @user23524697 did you see my last comment on chat?

Comment: yes I just saw your answer in the chat! I fixed the problem yesterday! I want to thank you! I will post the answer and give you the reputation points! Have a nice day! `:)`

Comment: @user23524697 it's nice that now your code works `:)` so finally the problem was your `if` statement? thanks for the bounty `:)`

Answer (score 0):

## Edit with working answer

```
// if product page is requested
        } else if (userPath.equals("/viewProduct")) {
            
            String productId = request.getQueryString();

            if (productId != null) {

                // get selected product
                selectedProduct = productFacade.find(Integer.parseInt(productId));

                // place selected product in session scope
                session.setAttribute("selectedProduct", selectedProduct);
                
            }
            
            userPath = "/product";
```